# Sorting strings

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to sort strings without using string array but it is giving error (Property or indexer 'string.this[int]' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only).I do not want to use any string builder or array methods.

```
string s = "aedcb";
string a = s;
char t;

for (int p = 0; p <= a.Length - 2; p++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= a.Length - 2; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] > a[i + 1])
        {
            t = a[i + 1];
            a[i + 1] = a[i];     //Here is the error
            a[i] = t;            //Here is the error

            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
    }
}

s = a.ToString();

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: You can't modify a string directly, it is immutable. Create a new string or use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Why exactly are you not using a built-in sorting method?

Comment: A string is immutable so it's only natural that you cannot manipulate it in the way you do. Is there any particular reason you are avoiding other data structures?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bubble Sort On Strings (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25897194/bubble-sort-on-strings-c) Please take the time to actually *read* the comments people posted on your previous question. Someone addressed this problem already in the last comment.

Comment: Additionally, please learn how to use Google. Just searching literally for `Property or indexer 'string.this[int]' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only` pulls up another SO question with the *exact same* problem.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Probably because this is homework.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior its not homework i just challenged myself

Comment: How about `s = new string(s.OrderBy(c => c).ToArray());`

Comment: @MuhammadAdeel Somehow I find that hard to believe since its clear you did not even google it and you are asking for help.

Comment: For this exercise, you should sort integers. Characters have an unbelievable number of nuances. You'll be doing yourself a disservice if you come to believe you've solved this without an in-depth study of Unicode.

Answer (score 9):

Strings are immutable. You'll need to call `ToCharArray()` and mutate that then do `new String(mutated)`

Answer (score 1):

This will loop through and put in the ascII order(alphabetical but case will effect). it loops through using a temporary value for the storage of the string.

```
    string sortString(string s)
    {
        string newString = s;
        for (int p = 0; p < s.Length; p++)
        {
            for (int i = p; i < s.Length; i++)
            {
                if (s[p] > s[i])
                {
                    newString = "";
                    for (int j = 0; j < s.Length; j++)
                    {
                        if (j == i)
                        {
                            newString += s[p];
                        }
                        else
                            if (j == p)
                            {
                                newString += s[i];

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                newString += s[j];

                            }
                    }
                    s = newString;
                }
            }

        }
        return newString;
    }
```

Comment: ASCII is a niche and archaic character set. .NET's `char` stores a single UTF-16 code unit, one or two of which encode a Unicode codepoint. (Of course, if two are needed then sorting them with code units from other codepoints will create gibberish and invalid code unit sequences.)

Answer (score 0):

This is how i did.First converted to .charArray as @darren kopp said.

```
    string a = "acegikmobdfhjln";
        char[] b = a.ToCharArray();
        char t;

        for (int h = 0; h < b.Length; h++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= b.Length - 2; i++)
            {
                if (b[i] > b[i + 1])
                {
                    t = b[i + 1];
                    b[i + 1] = b[i];
                    b[i] = t;

                }
            }

        }
        foreach (char item in b)

            Console.Write(item + " ");
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.ReadLine();
```